# Problem with drawing a plot in PyCharm using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, draw

I want to draw real time plot using matplotlib in PyCharm. When I run program I see only axis with no curve. When I run the same code on another computer all works. What can be the problem?

Checked the code on another computer in PyCharm with the same interpreter(Python 3.7) and version matplotlib 3.0.3 and it worked. In general, when I use method canvas.draw() it dosen't work too.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ch = np.linspace(1, 1024, 1024)
data = np.sin(ch * 0.01)
def animate(i, ch, data):

    for j in range(1, len(data)):
        data[j] = data[j] + random.random() - 0.5
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(ch, data)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ch, data), interval=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I solved it by turning off sciview mode. It acctually doesnt work. 
I am shocked.

Comment: Scientific View doesn't support animation at the moment, unfortunately. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27233